# wechaty fileBox.toFile raise exception 'uncaughtException Error: The stream is not readable. Maybe has already been consumed, and now it was drained

Tags: file, wechaty

I am trying to save image if wechat receive an image.

Following is my code:

```
async function onMessage(msg: Message) {
    if (msg.type() === bot.Message.Type.Image) {
        const fileBox = await msg.toFileBox();
        const fileName = `${fileBox.name}.png`;
        await fileBox.toFile(fileName, true);
        console.log(`Image has been downloaded as ${fileName}`);
    }
}
```

The code didn't read the stream, however, it raise error:

> uncaughtException Error: The stream is not readable. Maybe has already been consumed, and now it was drained. See: https://github.com/huan/file-box/issues/50
> at FileBox.toStream (/Users/linsimin/Code/Learnings/wechaty/wechaty-test/node_modules/file-box/src/file-box.ts:796:17)
> at FileBox.pipe (/Users/linsimin/Code/Learnings/wechaty/wechaty-test/node_modules/file-box/src/file-box.ts:1020:10)
> at /Users/linsimin/Code/Learnings/wechaty/wechaty-test/node_modules/file-box/src/file-box.ts:926:12
> at new Promise ()
> at FileBox.toFile (/Users/linsimin/Code/Learnings/wechaty/wechaty-test/node_modules/file-box/src/file-box.ts:921:11)
> at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
> at async WechatyImpl.onMessage (/Users/linsimin/Code/Learnings/wechaty/wechaty-test/src/wechat-bot.ts:47:9)

Github: https://github.com/timewalker08/wechaty-test